# How to override queryset count() method in Django's admin list

Tags: python, django, count, admin

In order to avoid time consuming and costly exact database count queries, I'd like to override the `count()` method inside a Django admin class like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import connection

class CountProxy:
    def __call__(self):
        # how to access the queryset `query` here?
        query = ...

        try:
            if not query.where:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = %s", [query.model._meta.db_table])
                n = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
                if n >= 1000: return n # exact count for small tables
            return object_list.count()
        except:
            # exception for lists
            return len(object_list)
        return estimated_count

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs.count = CountProxy()
        return qs
```

But I don#t know how to access the original queryset within my `CountProxy` class. Any idea? I know I can overwrite the whole `changelist` view through `get_changelist`. But that involves a lot of duplicating code from Django's repo.

Comment: `object_list` is not defined in your solution. `return estimated_count` is unreachable so will never execute, plus also undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong, but could you pass `qs` as an instance attribute for `CountProxy`?

```
class CountProxy:
    def __init__(self, query):
        self.query = query

    def __call__(self):
        # you've already had the query here, do something with self.query

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs.count = CountProxy(qs)
        return qs
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me with postgres and Django 2.2.x

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.db import connection

class FastCountQuerySet(QuerySet):
    """
    Fast count (estimate) queryset to speedup count
    """
    def count(self):
        """
        Override count queries (performed by Django ORM) to display approximate value.
        This will speed up count i.e. in the admin interface.
        """
        if self._result_cache is not None:
            return len(self._result_cache)

        query = self.query
        if not (query.group_by or query.where or query.distinct):
            # cursor = connections[self.db].cursor()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = %s", [self.query.model._meta.db_table])
            n = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
            if n >= 1000:
                return n  # exact count for small tables
            else:
                return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
        else:
            return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)


class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Custom db manager
    """
    def get_queryset(self):
        return FastCountQuerySet(self.model)
```

And finally override your model manager:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar before so I can help.

I defined a custom queryset class:

```
class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def count(self):
        """
        Override count queries (performed by Django ORM) to display approximate value.
        This will speed the admin interface.

        """
        if self._result_cache is not None and not self._iter:
            return len(self._result_cache)

        query = self.query
        if not (query.group_by or query.having or query.distinct):
            cursor = connections[self.db].cursor()
            cursor.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '%s';" % self.model._meta.db_table)
            return cursor.fetchall()[0][4]
        else:
            return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
```

Then defined a custom model manager:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model)
```

Then used it in my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
```

Comment: Good solution, but I cannot override the Model's object manager. I need to apply this special count method only within Django's admin interface.

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't really make sense as it is. What is `return qs._clone(klass=ApproxCountQuerySet)` supposed to do? The `klass` attribute is probably something from an external and non-visible code ... But this question/answer is actually the original of my own code/problem.

Comment: Upvoted your suggestion, because it may certainly be a solution for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the admin page faster for large counts you can define a wrapper of models.Admin that as queryset returns a queryset that instead of the normal count uses an approximate one only when results ain't filetered. This would work for Postgres 12 and Django 4.1.7:

```py
class FastCountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class FastCountQuerySet(QuerySet):
        def count(self):
            """
            Override count queries (performed by Django ORM) to display approximate value.
            This will speed up count in the admin interface.
            """

            if self._result_cache is not None:
                return len(self._result_cache)

            query = self.query
            if not (query.group_by or query.where or query.distinct):
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = %s", 
                    [self.model._meta.db_table])
                return int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
            else:
                return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return FastCountAdmin.FastCountQuerySet(qs.model, using=qs.db)
```

Then you can use it like that:

```py
class MyHugeModelAdmin(FastCountAdmin):
    model = MyHugeModel
```