# Optimising Django .count() function

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way to optimise the .count() function on a queryset in Django? I have a large table, which I have indexed, however the count function is still incredibly slow.

I am using the [Django Rest Framework Datatables](https://github.com/izimobil/django-rest-framework-datatables) package, which uses the count function, so I have no way of avoiding using the function - I was hoping there would be a way to utilise the index for the count or something along those lines?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: Count what? Can you please show *what* you try to achieve?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough. I have a table with 4.4m records. The Model.objects.all().count() function takes ~10 seconds to run, even though the Model.objects.all() call is almost instantaneous thanks to an index. I am looking for a way to optimise the .count() part.

Comment: the `.all()` will *always* be instantanuous: it does not make a query, querysets are lazy, with `.all()` you just make a queryset that *promises* to make a database query when you enumerate over it, but the query is not made proactively.

Comment: I appreciate that, it was just an example. My point is, using database indexes, my filtering is really quick - however I then need to count the queryset, and the count is really slow. When I evaluate the queryset without counting, it's milliseconds. When I then try and count the queryset, it's ~10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this issue in the future, it is a known issue with Postgres when counting a large amount of rows. We can instead estimate the number of rows (which seems to be highly accurate and infinitely quicker). Explanation of how to do this in Django is here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64013651/12206099

Answer (score 0):

You can make simpler version by using something like:

```
class CustomCount(Subquery):
    template = "(SELECT count(*) FROM (%(subquery)s) _count)"
    output_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Usage:

```
some_subquery = SomeModel.objects.filter(
    foregin_key=OuterRef("id")
).values("id")

qs.annotate(some_field_count=CustomCount(some_subquery))
```

Since this makes the simplest count query then I think it should be faster then default one (need to verify this)

If this still doesn't help then issue is somewhere else